# A series of eog command with auto-closed X-windows

Tags: linux, bash

eog 1.png

which triggers X-window pop-up and show the image in it.

There are 10 images (e.g. 1.png, 2.png ... 10.png)

I wrote a bash shell script like:

eog 1.png
eog 2.png
...
eog 10.png

When I run the script, I should hit 'q' in the keyboard to execute next command.
But, I want an automatic running of the script without keyboard return. 
Is there any good idea? 
I am considering such a process where X-windows closes after showing a few second then next command proceeds..

Answer (score 1):

`GNOME` image viewer, `eog` by default has an option to open images in a slide-show with an option `-s, --slide-show`

```
eog --slide-show /pathToPictures/
```

But you might also want to take a look at `yes (GNU coreutils)` which could be useful for automatic keyboard return of the characters. It basically answers the interactive prompt with whatever string you are passing to it.

Supposing that your script needs `q` every-time to execute a new command, you could run the script as:-

```
yes q | ./yourScript.sh
```

As for the time between two executions, you could add a `sleep` command between the executions to seconds (the default) or minutes or hours or days.

Comment: almost close to the answer what I expect.. But I want no keyboard return at all.

Comment: @user4914499: Agreed, can you explain a bit more on how do you want to handle it then?

Comment: I want to look at each image at a glance. It could be similar with autoslide function..

Comment: @user4914499: If you are looking for an alternate option `eog` by default has an option for slide show mode when you give ` -s ` or ` --slide-show` option. e.g. `eog -s /picture_directory/`. You do not keyboard interaction in that case.

Comment: But the slide option is not the case for me. In my case, all  image files are not existed in the beginning. e.g. 2.png is generated after showing up 1.png

Comment: @user4914499: Then I guess keyboard-return option is the best design for this, because you are not certain of when to expect the next image. Or can you use `expect` commands? It works by throwing a prompt interactively and the same can be answered from the script. more at http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114319/discussion-between-inian-and-user4914499).